# __FILE__ In .h what does it resolve to

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a specification on how the `__FILE__` macro will be expanded if it is in a `.h`?

If I define in `foo.h`

```
#define MYFILE __FILE__
```

And include it in `foo.c`

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
  printf("%s",MYFILE);
  ....
}
```

Does this output `foo.h` or `foo.c`?  (Yes I realize this is a stupid example)

Sorry for what should be a simple question.  The documentation on the web seems conflicting.  For what it is worth VS2008 comes back as `foo.c` which is what I would expect....I think. I am just trying to confirm if this is defined behavior.

Comment: The original poster did try it, he's asking whether that behavior is defined and portable.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers....I guess I was thinking too narrowly by only thinking to look in the spec at __FILE__.....when viewed as a generic macro it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The advice given in [yan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490562/yan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5047620) is 'generally correct'. That is, the value of `__FILE__` is the name of the current source file when the macro is used, not when the macro is defined. However, it is not absolutely correct - and here is a counter-example:

```
$ cat x.h
static void helper(void)
{
    printf("%s:%d helper\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
$ cat x.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "x.h"

int main(void)
{
    helper();
    printf("%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return 0;
}

$ make x
cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -g x.c -o x
$ ./x
x.h:3 helper
x.c:7
$
```

This is a contrived example; in C, you very seldom put actual code into a header as I did here — unless you are using `inline` functions.  But the output shows that there are circumstances where the name of the header can be the correct name that `__FILE__` expands to.

Comment: Actually, it's common to put inline functions in header files, so this isn't really all that contrived. +1 for the good point.

Comment: @Jim: you're right - if you're allowed to use that feature of C99.  Since (AFAIK) MSVC does not support inline functions for C compilations (C++ is a different story, of course), we're not allowed to use inline functions.  (Though I see from MSDN that MSVC allows `__inline`...hmmm, maybe there's hope yet.)

Comment: The C99 standard was adopted over a decade ago. I'm glad I don't have to develop with such broken tools.

Comment: @Jim: tell me about it.  Of course, one could ask when it was implemented - as opposed to adopted.  And you could also argue that MS never adopted it.  Also, I fear, the next C1X standard will be a much weaker standard; see the discussions on comp.std.c if you need to know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 10):

It will always return the .c where it's used, as `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are resolved after the pre-processor. This way, you can write debug macros that use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` and have them point to where the debug statements appear.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler makes good point in his answer ... if the code that uses __LINE__ or __FILE__ is in the header file, then the name of the header file is printed. This would be the case, e.g., for inline functions defined in header files.

Comment: I have problems with the claim that '`__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are resolved _after_ the pre-processor'.  They are resolved _by_ the pre-processor; the compiler proper doesn't see the underscore symbols.

Answer (score 5):

Macro expansion (of all macros, not just special ones like `__FILE__`) is done *after* `#include` substitution, so yes, this behaviour can be relied upon.

Answer (score 4):

The actual language in the standard is (§6.10.8):

> `__FILE__` The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal).

Because macro expansion happens after `#include`s are processed, the "current source file" is the preprocessed .c file being compiled.

Comment: The standard says that " A #include preprocessing directive causes the named header or source ﬁle to be processed from phase 1 through phase 4, recursively". So it is certainly possible (maybe even required) that the preprocessor know that it's a particular header file being processed when macros are expanded (in phase 4) for it. Also keep in mind that the "presumed name" of the current source file can be modified by the `#line` directive.

Answer (score 3):

That #define macro does literal text replacement pre-compilation.  By the time the C compiler hits your foo.c file, it sees:

```
printf("%s", __FILE__);
```

so you're getting foo.c.

Comment: Actually, the compiler proper sees `printf("%s","foo.c");`; `__FILE__` is a macro defined by and expanded by the preprocessor.