Can the expanded code of an inline function differ between 2 translation units?
Say I have a macro UNIQUE_NAME(PREFIX) that concatenates __LINE__ to PREFIX:
#define CONCAT2_EXPAND(a, b)    a ## b
#define CONCAT2(a, b)           CONCAT2_EXPAND(a, b)
#define UNIQUE_NAME(prefix)     CONCAT2(CONCAT2(prefix, _), __LINE__)

Now if this macro was to be used in an inline function, included in two different translation units, then the expanded code of the inline function would differ between the two translation units (unless they have the same includes).
Is this behavior defined, unspecified, implementation-defined, or undefined?

This is what I got during a code review:

You're caught between a rock and a hard place here. Using __LINE__ is a bad idea, because there's nothing preventing me from calling UNIQUE_NAME twice on the same line, and then it's not really unique any longer, is it? __COUNTER__ would give a unique name, but it'd be too unique: if UNIQUE_NAME was used in an inline function, included in two different translation units, then the expanded code of the inline function would differ between the two TUs (unless they have the same includes), which is Undefined Behavior. –
@Matthieu M.

If it helps, I am confused about having a static inline function and an inline function (if it matters which one) in a header file and including it in different .c files.
Say:
[[gnu::always_inline]] static inline void foo(void)
{
    bool UNIQUE_NAME(bar);
    // ...
}

and
inline void foo(void)
{
    bool UNIQUE_NAME(bar);
    // ...
}

I believe the reviewer meant the second one, and not the first one.

Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047597/file-in-h-what-does-it-resolve-to I believe the accepted answer is explicitly addressing your question.

@EugeneSh. I think not. That question is asking what __FILE__ would expand to different files, not if it is defined behavior if the contents of an inline function are different across two translation units.

The answer is showing that it will expand to the filename and line number of the header file the inline function is being defined in, I believe it is pretty much what you are asking, no? Except the language-lawyer stuff. From reading the standard I don't see much details about the behavior, so it looks like it can be interpreted differently by the implementation.

For instance the behavior described in the aforementioned answer is quite puzzling me, as per the C standard "A C program need not all be translated at the same time. The text of the program is kept in units called source files, (or preprocessing files) in this International Standard. A source file together with all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing directive #include is known as a preprocessing translation unit. After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation unit is called a translation unit."


which to me implies that these macros should be only expanded after  the header is included.


@EugeneSh. I have edited the question to add some code. My question is not what it would expand to (probably different line numbers), but whether an inline function is allowed to expand to code that differs between two or more translation units.

You left out static in your latest edit; is this intentional?  Could you please put back the actual definition of the function in question?  The details may be important.

@NateEldredge I became confused between static inline and inline. In a code review, the behavior was mentioned to be undefined for an inline function, so inline I have kept it. I'd add what the reviewer said verbatim.

I see.. perhaps it is exactly the answer to my doubt I stated above :) The fact that it is expanding to the header file name/line is working around this issue, as it will always expand to the same no matter where it is being included at.... but in general different TUs can have different static functions with the same name but different implementation.

static inline is different from inline in the sense, that you can't have two TUs including the header with just inline, as it will constitute duplicate definition. static will make it "visible" only in the including TUs, so each can have it's own copy.

Once again, please include full example code for the function(s) you have in mind.  You keep talking about "an inline function" but C does not use such terminology so it is unclear exactly what you mean.

@NateEldredge Well, I am only repeating after the reviewer :). But sure, give me a moment.

@EugeneSh.: Yes you can, I believe, so long as they don't also contain a declaration of the function with extern.  See 6.7.4p7.

@NateEldredge The functions are extern by default, aren't they? UPD: Ah, in fact it says "An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function". OK, I need to test it out..

@NateEldredge I have added two examples of what I have in mind. I believe the reviewer meant the second one, and not the first one.

IMO, using inline without static leads to confusion — I don't do it in my own code.  Using static inline … avoids most (if not all) of the problems with definitions vs uses. The residual issue is "if the function is not inlined, then each object file that calls the function has a copy of the function". For me, that's an acceptable risk. If the function might not be inlined, it probably shouldn't be declared inline. GCC seems to inline functions extensively — creating a static (not inline) function that's called from one line of code in the file often leads to that function being inlined.

FWIW I just tried to use just inline and for some reason gcc is giving errors about undefined references to this function even though it is clearly defined in the included header. No idea why. Adding static makes it to compile.

@Harith — see what I mean (here).    As an addendum to that prior comment — if you were willing to have the function expanded inline every time it is used, you can't really object to having a copy of the function in the object file it if it not inlined.

Why do you need a unique name inside the inline function?  The local variable names in an inline function are completely disjoint from the names in any function where it is inlined — one of the many benefits of using inline functions instead of macros to achieve inlined code.

@EugeneSh.: This is allowed; when you define with inline void foo(void) { ... }, you have created an inline definition of a function with external linkage, which is not an external definition.  But there still needs to be an external definition, and the compiler is allowed to use it instead of the inline definition (it is unspecified which is used).  So in your example, the compiler probably declined to inline the function for whatever reason, emitted call foo instead, and then failed to link because there is no out-of-line definition of foo.

If you use static inline, then everything is fine.  Then you simply have (conceptually) a static function in each translation unit, and they are fully independent of each other; the same way that static functions have always worked in C.  Adding inline doesn't change these semantics; the difference between static and static inline is effectively just a hint to the compiler that inlining might be a good idea, but it remains free to inline or not, with or without the keyword.
If you just use inline, now the function has external linkage and you have created an inline definition under 6.7.4p7.  This is not an external definition of foo(), and it still needs to have one under 6.9p5, so you'll have to provide one elsewhere.  This could be done by including a definition of foo (without inline) in some third translation unit which does not include the header.  Or, by adding the declaration extern void foo(void); to exactly one of the translation units which does include the header, in which case the definition in that translation unit is no longer an inline definition (despite the inline keyword) and becomes a regular external definition.  See Example 1 in 6.7.4p10.
This does have a practical advantage (in a typical implementation) in that if there are instances where the function cannot be inlined, then all such instances from all translation units can call the same single out-of-line copy of the function.  If you define it static inline then you may get a separate out-of-line copy per translation unit, which makes your executable larger, increases memory usage, makes caching less efficient, etc (though the effects may or may not actually be significant).
Note that on typical implementations, if the compiler actually is able to inline every instance of the function, it may never actually need to look for the external definition, and thus may not complain if it doesn't exist.  But the standard still requires it.
As far as I know, C doesn't actually require that the inline definitions agree with each other, nor with the external definition.  However, when they both exist, then in any given place where the function is called, it is unspecified which definition is actually executed, and this could lead to confusion.
The reviewer might be thinking about the rule that a function cannot have more than one external definition (whether they are identical or not).  However, as it stands you don't have multiple external definitions; in fact you don't have any (which is still bad but for a different reason).  If you add an external definition in one translation unit, then you'll have exactly one, which is what's required.
The reviewer might also be thinking of C++ which does have a rule that inline definitions of a function must all be identical (C++20 6.3p13).  But as far as I know, C does not have such a rule.

As the reviewer, I confirm that I was not aware that this was a point a divergence between the C and C++ standards.
